# CppCoreGuidlines R.33 Why pass `unique_ptr` by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, cpp-core-guidelines

The [CppCoreGuidlines rule R.33](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r33-take-a-unique_ptrwidget-parameter-to-express-that-a-function-reseats-thewidget) suggests to

> Take a `unique_ptr<widget>&` parameter to express that a function
> reseats the widget.
>
> Reason Using `unique_ptr` in this way both documents and enforces the
> function call’s reseating semantics.
>
> Note “reseat” means “making a pointer or a smart pointer refer to a
> different object.”

I don't understand why we should pass by reference when reseat means "making a pointer or a smart pointer refer to a different object.”

When the function's purpose is to reseat/change the underlying object the pointer is pointing to, aren't we stealing the ownership from the caller this way and therefore should pass the `unique_ptr` by value, hence moving it and transferring ownership?

Is there an example that explains why passing a `unique_ptr` by reference is recommended?

Comment: The point is to *not* transfer ownership. The caller retains ownership of *an* object, but the function replaces it with a different object.

Comment: if you pass by value then you can't change the pointer at all?

Comment: Because that will allow the "reseat" function (the function being called) to actually *reseat* the pointer? I.e. reset it and make it point somewhere else.

Comment: In case we make it point somewhere else, what happens to the object it pointed before? Aren't we leaking memory in this case?

Comment: @AlanBirtles as far as I understand, if we pass a unique pointer by value, the called function becomes the owner because the move constructor is called.

Comment: [Resetting](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) a smart pointer does the right thing and handles freeing the old object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the function's purpose is to reseat/change the underlying object the pointer is pointing to, aren't we stealing the ownership from the caller this way

No. Neither when we "reseat" a pointer, nor when we change the pointed object, do we take ownership of the pointer i.e. we aren't transferring the ownership.

> Is there an example that explains why passing a unique_ptr by reference is recommended?

Here is an example of a function that "reseats" a unique pointer:

```
void reseat(std::unique_ptr<widget>& ptr) {
    ptr = std::make_unique<widget>();
}
```

If you tried to use a reference to const, then that wouldn't compile at all. If you tried to use a non-reference parameter, then the argument pointer wouldn't be modified and thus the behaviour wouldn't be as desired. The caller would be forced to move their pointer leaving it always null.

You could modify the example to use a pointer to unique pointer, but references are recommended because it isn't possible to pass null by mistake. A reference wrapper would also work, but it would be unnecessarily complicated.

> In case we make it point somewhere else, what happens to the object it pointed before?

If a unique pointer points to something other than null, then making it point elsewhere will cause the previously pointed object to be deleted.

> Aren't we leaking memory in this case?

No.

---

Note that the example is simple in order to be easy to understand. Typically I wouldn't recommend to write such function and instead considering to write a function that returns the new unique pointer, and let the caller "reseat" the pointer themselves. But that depends on details.

Comment: Instead of creating a new `unique_ptr` inside your `reseat` function using `std::make_unique`, would using `std::unique_ptr::reset` also be possible to reseat the underlying object?

Comment: @evolved The usage of `reset` implies that you have an owning bare pointer to pass as an argument to `reset` (unless you reset to null). I would recommend against having owning bare pointers in the first place. But yes, it's possible.

Comment: How often does it happen that we have a function where we pass a `unique_ptr` by reference to reseat the widget? Is this common practice in modern C++? Or are you also recommending *not* to pass a unique pointer by reference and let the caller do the reseat?

Comment: One common scenario is that the reseating happens only sometimes based on some condition.

Comment: @evolved You'll have to ask that from someone who has researched the frequency of argument usage in C++. It's not anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: I wonder if these usecases one could just use a different API: `std::unique_ptr<widget> reseat(std::unique_ptr<widget> ptr) { return std::make_unique<widget>(); }`, and the caller would do `ptr = reseat(std::move(ptr));`.